# Queries from Diffrent Tables How to Join Suggest PLease (PHP)(SQL)

Tags: php, sql

I need help regarding JOIN tables to get category name & author name from other tables.

for articles site I have Three Tables

- articles
- categories
- users

Articles Table structure :

```
id
title
slug
content
category
author
date
```

I save category ID & user ID in articles table with each article

While Displaying Articles for a category I use this:
(just some draft idea not full code)

```
localhost/testsite/category.php?cat=category-slug

$catslug = ($_GET["cat"]);

//GET CAT ID from category table from slug

$qry = "SELECT * from category WHERE slug='$catslug';
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die("Error in Query");
$ans = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$cid = $ans['id'];
$catname = $ans['title'];

<h2><?php echo $catname; ?></h2>

//after getting cat-id query to get article of that ID

$aqry = select * from article where category=$cid ORDER BY date";
$ares = mysql_query($aqry) or die("Error in Query");
$aans = mysql_fetch_array($ares))
$aid = $aans['author'];

//then another query to get author name from users
select username from users where id=$aid
```

I m learning PHP & not much familiar with JOIN statement & combining queries
need help/suggestions hw can I achieve same with JOIN tables instead of different queries to get catname and author name from tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
SELECT distinct c.title, U.Username
from category C join article A on A.category=C.id
join users U on U.id=A.author
WHERE C.slug= :catslug
```

Comment: pls explain this query to me 
i know about join but not much about distinct

Comment: distinct will get only one occurence of the fields, eliminating duplicates. Like you would do with group by. To be honest I don't remeber if mysql uses this syntax or the fields must be put in parentesis.

Comment: thanks a lot for direction I got it with some changes :))
removed distinct as I want to fetch all articles from that category
also removed U.id = A.author condition I want to list all articles not any single author only to pick author name from users table.

Comment: `SELECT C.*, A.*, U.username
   from categories C 
   JOIN articles A on A.category=C.id
   JOIN users U 
   WHERE C.slug= '$cats'";`
Its working where single article in a category but to list all articles in a category I use WHILE
`while($ans = mysql_fetch_array($res))`

Its showing random result ALSO author name shows random username. hw to use in while

Comment: What you mean by random result? They are not sorted? if yes just add "Order by A.Title (or whatever you want to sort) at the end of your query. If not I think is better if you open a new question.

Comment: not order by ! when I use while looop with this query in categories with 2 articles I got 3 results 1 repeat result with different author name article title & content correct but author name different.

Comment: That because of the data you have in the 3 tables. you get all the combination. I suggest you to use group by (or distinct, depends) to avoid duplications

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Category id is foreign jey in article table

Try this query

```
select username from users
where id in (
select author from category cat
inner join article art 
on cat.category_id =art.category_id
where cat.slug= $cat
order by art.date desc )
```

Comment: category id, author id not foreign keys in articles table 

hmmmmmm
I should set up foreign keys in articles to speed up process.
I will try with this

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT article.*
        FROM article
             LEFT JOIN category
             ON article.category = category.ID
             LEFT JOIN users
             ON article.author = users.ID
       WHERE article.slug = :slug";
```

`:slug` is where you would insert (bind if you're using PDO) `$_GET['slug']`

Comment: I tried    
`$q="SELECT articles.* from articles 
   LEFT JOIN categories
   on articles.category = categories.id
   LEFT JOIN users
   on articles.author = users.id
   WHERE categories.slug = '$cats'";`
I changed WHERE category.slug since I want to get articles from a single category query by slug via $_GET in $cats
It Result in Error in Query

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should write a stored proc... but here's how you would get articles by categoryID that includes both the category name and user name.

Given the following table structures:

```
article
---------
articleID <- primary key
title
slug
content
categoryID <- foreign key
userID <- foreign key
createdDT

category
--------
categoryID <- primary key
categoryName

user
--------
userID <- primary key
userName
```

Here's how to write the query using joins:

```
SELECT a.title, a.slug, a.content, a.createdDT, c.categoryName, u.userName

FROM dbo.article a

JOIN dbo.category c on a.categoryID = c.categoryID
JOIN dbo.user u on a.userID = u.userID

WHERE a.categoryID = @categoryID
```

Here's an article from Microsoft on JOINs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx

Comment: here @CategoryID is Value from $_GET ?

Comment: If you created a stored procedure, @CategoryID would be one of the input parameters.  If you use inline query, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some different thing with a SQL request. You can do some join in your SQL request but you can also do another SELECT statement in your request Like

```
SELECT SOMETHINGS FROM A_TABLE WHERE (SELECT ANOTHER_THING FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE VALUE =1
```

But this statement will only work if you have 1 result in your second request

If you want to join two table with some value, you'll have to do it like this

```
SELECT something FROM a_table  AS alias1 JOIN another_table AS alias2 
ON alias1.value1 = alias2.value1 and .....
```

You can compare all the value that you want from one table to another and you can also join more than two table and the ON key word is not requested by sql syntax you can just do

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 join table_2
```

and it will show you all thje data from two table but be sure that this is the data you want this kind of little query can have some big result and slow down your app

you can read more there http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html